# No format security warnings in Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, llvm, string-formatting, xcode4.4

I don't get any format security warnings (`-Wformat-security`) from this code using Xcode 4.4:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // a = @"%@" or a = @"%@%@"
        NSString *a = [@"%@" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", arc4random_uniform(2)? @"%@": @"", nil];

        // 50% change of crash, but no warning
        NSLog(a, @"Hello, World!");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this normal or have I somehow disabled this warning in Xcode?

I have just created the project with this code, so it haven't changed the project settings from the default.

Comment: Xcode 4.4 uses a new version of LLVM and Clang, did previous versions of Xcode cause -Wformat-security to light up?

Comment: @jessedc yeah it showed it in Xcode 4.2 at least. I don't know about Xcode 4.3.

Comment: hmm... It really is a LLVM question.