# how can I disable format-security error with clang?

Tags: c++, clang++, diagnostics

Im tryng to compile a project (dhewm 3, a doom 3 modification) and im unable to do so because it uses "insecure code" , I understand why it is a security concernt but im unable to fix it, fixed the rest of the "errors" but this one is tricky, and im prety sure its safe.
anyways , im unable to disable the error format-security

how can I disable format-security error?, using clang 6

this is the cmd line:

```
clang++  -D__DOOM_DLL__ -I/home/pvd/Devel/root/include -I/home/pvd/Devel/root/include/AL -I/home/pvd/Devel/root/include/SDL2 -I/home/pvd/Devel/dhewm3/neo/build -I/home/pvd/Devel/dhewm3/neo   -Wno-error=format-security -Wno-format-security -g -O2 -ffast-math -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations -fomit-frame-pointer   -pipe -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-switch -Wno-format-security -Wno-error=format-security -Woverloaded-virtual -o CMakeFiles/dhewm3.dir/framework/Console.cpp.o -c /home/pvd/Devel/dhewm3/neo/framework/Console.cpp
```

this is the error:

```
/home/pvd/Devel/dhewm3/neo/framework/Console.cpp:283:30: error: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Werror,-Wformat-security]
                SCR_DrawTextRightAlign( y, msg );
                                           ^~~
/home/pvd/Devel/dhewm3/neo/framework/Console.cpp:283:30: note: treat the string as an argument to avoid this
                SCR_DrawTextRightAlign( y, msg );
                                           ^
                                           "%s", 
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Have you tried `-Wno-format-security`?

Comment: yep, no luck with that, I tried -Wno-format-security and -Wno-error=format-security

Comment: Try `-Wformat=0`

Comment: @CinderBiscuits it does not work. just checked , im fixing the errors one by one.

Comment: @alter Check the answer now, there is another option you can persue (***WARNING: EXTREMELY UNSAFE***), which is to downgrade your LLVM version into Apple LLVM Clang 3.0

Comment: Just to complete the collection of bad ideas: removing the printf attribute on line 44 of Console.cpp should also silence the error. (Note: don't do that, add a "%s" formatting string to the call instead, as suggested by the one answer)

Comment: yep, that's how im fixing the error, adding the format string. but it is in a lot of places., just want to disable the checking as an error.

Answer (score 1):

Format is something like a language,  could be considered something like executable code, this can be dangerous.

Imagine a format string that comes from a file, or from a variable.  If this file is compromised, anything could be implanted, like things that could potentially expose some parts of your memory or at least crash the application.

Imagine one could implant something like "%s", where one of the parameters was null for example,  this is a crash (on old systems a lot of problems would happen here, like dumping memory from this address until finding nearest null).

Your solution is like the compiler said:

```
SCR_DrawTextRightAlign( y, "%s", msg );
```

Because if `msg` as a variable has "%s" inside for example, and there is no other parameter, it would try to print the string at an undefined pointer, this is insecure and may crash (crash if you are lucky).

It would become like that:

```
SCR_DrawTextRightAlign( y, "Someone implanted: %s" );
```

%s will try to go to the memory pointed to by the parameter (which is now undefined, could be anything as the compiler and processor put on the stack/registers), and print character by character until a null is found.

Imagine this pointer was randomly pointing to something sensitive like API tokens, passwords, etc... This would be printed in front of the user.

Please correct it, don't try to skip it. If you would make the `msg` dynamic, you would sanitize it manually if you want to keep the code as it is.

So that any "%s" should be "%%s", so you would manually search for any % and add another % to it.

***EDIT:*** If editing the code is not an option, try an old version of LLVM, 
[No format security warnings in Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838220/no-format-security-warnings-in-xcode-4-4)
This question hints that Xcode 4.2 is the last thing to support disabling the formatting, which hints to Apple LLVM Clang version 3.0

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_3.0_-_Xcode_4.x

Comment: thanks you , so its a compiler bug?,  something to add: the %n in the format string can be very dangerous, since you can modify memory.i mean it ignores the option to disable that error/warning.

Comment: When you force LLVM/GCC to ignore this error/warning, it doesn't ignore `%s` nor `%n`, it ignore ***THE CHECKING***, so it PERMITS this dangerous operation to run, so, do it ONLY if you are 100% sure that the format string doesn't come from external source (such as a file, or user input), and that it can't be exploited in %s, %n, etc... Also you can sanitize it (think like SQL injection).  And it is not a compiler bug, the `printf` itself is something old. And removing the ability to silence this warning is not a bug, it is a feature.

Comment: i know that its going to ignore the checking , i want to know how to do it in clang 6,  im on linux

Comment: I don't find it in the new documentations, it seems to be removed, also another StackOverflow question suggests that Xcode >= 4.3 (which means > LLVM 3.0) doesn't support that.  {LLVM 3.0 on Linux is lke itself in macOS}

Answer (score 0):

I could not turn off 'format-security-error' setting in clang.
For example, this flag had no effect '-Wno-format-security'.
As @user9335 suggests, I got rid of the error by adding a %s. So I changed

fptrintf(log-file, printBuffer);

to:

```
fprintf(log-file, "%s",printBuffer);
```